# Selenium Multitab issue

Tags: python, selenium

I have an issue in selenium. With my code I should be able to click on an image and wait 3 seconds. In this process it opens several tabs. I don't know how to close these tabs.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=".\chromedriver.exe")
#
links = ["http://activeation.com/4W79",
         "http://activeation.com/4W89",
         "http://activeation.com/36ky",
         "http://activeation.com/36X5",
         "http://activeation.com/38QK",
         "http://activeation.com/4VdE",
         "http://activeation.com/4Vwm",
         "http://activeation.com/4Vxi",
         "http://activeation.com/4VyU",
         "http://activeation.com/4Vza",
         "http://activeation.com/4W0T"]

while True:
    for link in links:
        driver.get(link)
        time.sleep(6)
        element = driver.find_element_by_id("skip_bu2tton")
        actionchains = ActionChains(driver)
        actionchains.double_click(element).perform()
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: please ignore last 2 lines. driver.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
        driver.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')

Comment: Look at the answer from alien_frog for how to close a tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If several new windows/tabs might be opened after you navigate to new URL, you might need to use below code to close each window/tab except the base window:

```
# Define the base window
current = driver.current_window_handle

# Naviagte through list of URLs. No while loop needed
for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(6)

    driver.find_element_by_id("skip_bu2tton").click()

    # Check each window
    for window in driver.window_handles:
        # If window is not a base window
        if window != current:
            # ...switch to that window...
            driver.switch_to.window(window)
            # ...close it...
            driver.close()
            # ...switch back to base window
            driver.switch_to.window(current)
```